# How to implement generic type-safe deep cloning in a Java class hierarchy?

Tags: java, generics, casting, unchecked

I have a base class, say `Base` which specifies the abstract method `deepCopy`, and a myriad of subclasses, say `A`, `B`, `C`, ... `Z`. How can I define `deepCopy` so that its signature is `public X deepCopy()` for each class `X`?

Right, now, I have:

```
abstract class Base {
  public abstract Base deepCopy();
}
```

Unfortunately, that means that if if I have an object from a subclass, say `a` of `A`, then I always have to perform an unchecked cast for a more specific deep copy:

```
A aCopy = (A) a.deepCopy();
```

Is there a way, perhaps using generics, to avoid casting? I want to guarantee that any deep copy returns an object of the same runtime class.

Edit: Let me extend my answer as covariant typing isn't enough. Say, I then wanted to implement a method like:

```
static <N extends Base> List<N> copyNodes(List<N> nodes) {
    List<N> list = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (N node : nodes) {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      N copy = (N) node.deepCopy();
      list.add(copy);
    }
    return list;
  }
```

How could I avoid the unchecked warning?

Comment: There are a couple of utilities that will do this for you... http://www.genericdeepcopy.com/ and http://code.google.com/p/cloning/.

Answer (score 5):

Java 5 supports covariant return types which means that you can implement your `deepCopy()` method in each subclass to return the specific sub-class instance; e.g.

```
public class Z extends Base {
  @Override
  public Z deepCopy() {

  }
}
```

More on covariant return types [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/JDCTechTips/2004/tt1201.html#2).

Comment: Thanks! I guess you answered my original question, but didn't quite solve my problem. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is really not pretty, and I probably wouldn't do it myself, but:

```
    public abstract class Base<T extends Base<T>> {
    public abstract T deepCopy();
}
public class Extender extends Base<Extender> {

    @Override
    public Extender deepCopy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Or....

```
    public abstract class Base<T extends Base<T>> {
    public abstract T deepCopy();
}
public class Extender<T extends Base<T>> extends Base<T> {

    @Override
    public T deepCopy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, this is the only way to specify that a subclass must return an object of its own type.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
public interface DeeplyCloneable <T extends Cloneable> {
    public T deepClone();
}
```

Then... for example... (with errors, but good intentions; help!)

```
public class DeeplyClonableHashTable

         <T1 extends DeeplyCloneable<?>,T2 extends DeeplyCloneable<?>> 
extends Hashtable<T1,T2>
implements DeeplyCloneable<Hashtable<T1,T2>>{

@Override
public Hashtable<T1, T2> deepClone() {
  Object o = super.clone();
  if ((o == null) || (! (o instanceof DeeplyClonableHashTable<?,?>)))
  {
    throw new DeepCloneException(
      "Object instance does not support deepCloneing.");
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  DeeplyClonableHashTable<T1,T2> copy = (DeeplyClonableHashTable<T1,T2>)o;
  Set<T1> keys = copy.keySet();

  for (T1 key: keys){
    T2 value = this.get(key);
    T1 keyCopy = key.deepClone();  // this line is in error
    T2 valueCopy = value.deepClone();  // this line is in error
    copy.put(keyCopy, valueCopy);
  }
  return copy;
  }
}
```